# Can Ballerina-Composer be used with Ballerina V 1.0?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

I have seen several posts about ballerina-composer. But I couldn't find a proper place to download it or docs regarding it in [official site](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/). Also checked in ballerina installed location, whether I can start it with composer.bat, but nothing worked. I'm confused how to get installed it or doesn't it use nowadays with Ballerina v 1.0?
Could you please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have deprecated the composer distribution and instead, we have included the composer capability to the VSCode Plugin itself.
Please refer the following for more detailed explanation about the features

1. [Graphical Editor](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/tools-ides/vscode-plugin/graphical-editor/)
2. [Run and Debug](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/tools-ides/vscode-plugin/run-and-debug/)
3. [Language Intelligence](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/tools-ides/vscode-plugin/language-intelligence/)
4. [Documentation Viewer](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/tools-ides/vscode-plugin/documentation-viewer/)

Answer (score 2):

Ballerina composer is now deprecated in favor of VS Code plugin.
You can just install it from VS Code extensions pane.

[image]

[image]